# Enforce Permission for Facebook's JS-SDK

Tags: facebook, api, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

My login code looks like so:

```
FB.login(statusChangedHandler, {
  scope: 'email,'
});
```

I would like to enforce the email permission in such way that a user who
disabled it would not have the ability to login to the app - he will get an
 error message and be prompted to login again.

Is there any built-in (Facebook's) method of doing such a process?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t enforce it, you can only check after the authorization. An easy way is to use `return_scopes`, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.3#permissions